# How to find analytical solution for integral from product of Bessel functions of second kind with different order?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

I need help with analytical solution for the following integral:

```
$Assumptions = 
 k \[Element] Reals && r \[Element] Reals && k > 0 && r > 0 && 
  n >= 0 && n \[Element] Integers && a \[Element] Reals && 
  b \[Element] Reals && a > 0 && b > 0 && b > a
tmpI = Integrate[BesselY[-1 + n, k*r] BesselY[n, k*r], {r, a, b}]
```

After simplification of result (tmpI) I get Indeterminate. It looks like Mathematica 11 uses transformations for BesselY corresponding to non-integer order despite of the assumptions I've specified.

Comment: do you have some reason to expect an analytic result?  Do you get useful results for specific values of the parameters?  You may want to try math.stackexchange.com if you think this has a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the integral for certain values of n = 0,1,2,3,... and you will find a rule for it for n>=2

Here for n=0

```
 int[k_, a_, b_, 0] = 
 Assuming[k \[Element] Reals && r \[Element] Reals && k > 0 && r > 0 &&
 n >= 0 && n \[Element] Integers && a \[Element] Reals && 
 b \[Element] Reals && a > 0 && b > 0 && b > a, 
 Integrate[BesselY[-1 + n, k*r] BesselY[n, k*r] /. n -> 0, {r, a, b}]]

 (*   (-BesselY[0, a k]^2 + BesselY[0, b k]^2)/(2 k)   *)
```

Here for n=1

```
    int[k_, a_, b_, 1] = 
     Assuming[k \[Element] Reals && r \[Element] Reals && k > 0 && r >0 &&
     n >= 0 && n \[Element] Integers && a \[Element] Reals && 
     b \[Element] Reals && a > 0 && b > 0 && b > a, 
     Integrate[BesselY[-1 + n, k*r] BesselY[n, k*r] /. n -> 1, {r, a, b}]]

    (*  (BesselY[0, a k]^2 - BesselY[0, b k]^2)/(2 k)   *)
```

Here for n=2

```
    int[k_, a_, b_, 2] = 
    Assuming[k \[Element] Reals && r \[Element] Reals && k > 0 && r > 0 &&
    n >= 0 && n \[Element] Integers && a \[Element] Reals && 
    b \[Element] Reals && a > 0 && b > 0 && b > a, 
    Integrate[BesselY[-1 + n, k*r] BesselY[n, k*r] /. n -> 2, {r, a, b}]]

   (*  (1/(2 Sqrt[\[Pi]]))(2 a MeijerG[{{}, {-1, 0, 1/
       2}}, {{-(3/2), -(1/2), -(1/2), 3/2}, {-1}}, a k, 1/2] - 
      2 b MeijerG[{{}, {-1, 0, 1/2}}, {{-(3/2), -(1/2), -(1/2), 3/
      2}, {-1}}, b k, 1/2] - 
      a MeijerG[{{0, 1/2}, {}}, {{3/2}, {-(3/2), -(1/2), -(1/2)}}, a k, 1/
      2] + b MeijerG[{{0, 1/2}, {}}, {{3/2}, {-(3/2), -(1/2), -(1/2)}}, 
       b k, 1/2])    *)
```

Calculating for n=3,4,5,6,.. you can extract the general rule

```
    intn[k_, a_, b_, n_] = 
     1/(2 Sqrt[\[Pi]]) (2 a MeijerG[{{}, {1 - n, 0, 1/
     2}}, {{-((2 n - 1)/2), -(1/2), -(1/2), (2 n - 1)/2}, {1 - n}},
     a k, 1/2] - 
     2 b MeijerG[{{}, {1 - n, 0, 1/
     2}}, {{-((2 n - 1)/2), -(1/2), -(1/2), (2 n - 1)/2}, {1 - n}},
     b k, 1/2] - 
     a MeijerG[{{0, 1/2}, {}}, {{(2 n - 1)/
     2}, {-((2 n - 1)/2), -(1/2), -(1/2)}}, a k, 1/2] + 
     b MeijerG[{{0, 1/2}, {}}, {{(2 n - 1)/
     2}, {-((2 n - 1)/2), -(1/2), -(1/2)}}, b k, 1/2])
```

Test it with numerical integration and you will see, it works for all n>=2

```
    nint[k_, a_, b_, n_] := 
    NIntegrate[BesselY[-1 + n, k*r] BesselY[n, k*r], {r, a, b}]

    {nint[1, 2, 3, 5], intn[1., 2, 3, 5]}

    (* {8.11274, 8.11274}   *)
```

Comment: Which of Mathematica versions gives these nice results? Version 11.0.1 returns integrals unevaluated for n>=2.

Comment: @Shinrei, I used Version 8.0.